What is the typical impedance of a universal motor for electric noises it generates?
The question: What is the typical impedance of a universal electric motor rated as 220 V / 50 Hz / 1200 W used in home appliances for the electric noises the motor itself generates? I've read that the noises are typically in the 10 kHz-20 kHz range.
How the question occurred to me (details perhaps not necessary for answering the question):
I have a motor from a vacuum cleaner with a broken and burnt capacitor. The motor seems to be of universal type with ratings mentioned above, and the capacitor apparently is an EMI suppression capacitor, and I'm going to replace the capacitor as well as learn more about electrical engineering in this process (I'm a physicist by training).
The capacitor is marked as PZB 300 MC, which is a "metallized paper capacitor" designed for EMI suppression in a delta configuration (150 nF X2 + 2 x 4700 pF Y). The ground lead of the capacitor is simply connected to the metallic case of the motor. That's it. The AC power sockets and plugs don't have a ground connection in my country.
So far I've decided to replace it with an MKP capacitor of X2 class. But what capacitance should I choose? I think at noise frequencies the reactance of the capacitor should be much less than the impedance of the motor. So I need to know the latter.
By the way, two technicians told me I can remove the capacitor completely and power the motor with no worries! I guess they are wrong.

"By the way, two technicians told me I can remove the capacitor completely and power the motor with no worries! I guess they are wrong."  They are right - the motor will run.  The problem is that the motor will then broadcast a lot of electrical noise which can cause problems for other receivers.

@JRE, Yes, I'm aware of that.

@JRE, "the motor will run". Yes. But won't the noise affect the performance and lifetime of the motor in some ways, in addition to causing "problems for other receivers"?

The brushes will spark more and therefore wear out sooner - but it's not like "it'll stop working tomorrow."  It's more like "you might have to replace the brushes before something else breaks."

What capacitance? Presumably the designers considered that 150nF across the motor was adequate. The two 4700pF caps are important as well.
